# Why python's global variable can not be used in other functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, variables

I want to receive string data from server continuously using while loop and thread and then I want to do something use this string data that I receive from server so I have decided to use global variable.

But when I use global variable, python says this variable is not defined. I have tried to solve this but I still don't know why. I hope you help me. Thank you for reading.

```
global order
def receive():
    while True:
        order = client.recv(1)
        order = order.decode()

def execution():
    if order == "1":
        print("1")
    elif order == "2":
        print("2")

receiver = threading.Thread(target=receive, args=())
receiver.start()

execution()
```

result: order is not defined.

Comment: `global` goes in each function that wants to assign to the global. It doesn't go outside the functions. There's a duplicate around here somewhere.

Comment: (Also this is a really bad way to communicate between threads, and it'll cause data loss and other problems.)

Comment: Thank you. I think I should think about the other ways..

Answer (score 0):

You're using global the wrong way. Try this instead:

```
order

def receive():
    global order
    while True:
        order = client.recv(1)
        order = order.decode()

def execution():
    global order
    if order == "1":
        print("1")
    elif order == "2":
        print("2")

receiver = threading.Thread(target=receive, args=())
receiver.start()

execution()
```

Comment: @allentando What doesn't work? Is there an error message?